# JList with no options isn't working

Tags: java, swing, java-7, jlist, japplet

So I have the below JList:

```
    String[] books_name = {"Deitel-Java How to Program", "Horstmann-Big Java", "Lewis-Software Solutions" };

JList ip_list_books = new JList( books_name );
```

but for some reason the app doesnt build, I am using Compilr.com, and its not returning any proper errors.

Type    File    Line    Column  Description
Note    null    null     Project.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note    null    null     Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

I have tried -Xlint:unchecked, same thing shows up.

What am I doing wrong? What's wrong with the jlist?

Comment: Try something like `JList<String> ip_list_books = new JList<>(books_name);` instead?

Comment: Thanks, that actually worked, may I know why my app wasnt building before? and how can I make the above code work?

Comment: Are you sure this is the part of code that is causing the build issue. Because I didn't find anything wrong in your original code and I've also just tried in compilr.com and it worked fine.

Comment: well when I removed that code it worked fine, and when I used `JList<String> ip_list_books = new JList<>(books_name);` it ran just fine.

Comment: @AhouraGhotbi Since Java 7, `JList` now accepts generics (as part of it's agreement with the model). What the error is telling you is basically, the `JList` was expecting `Object[]` but you were providing a `String[]` array.  This is actually just warning (normally).  By adding the <String> to declaration, we are now telling the compiler that this `JList` is expecting `String` elements